# Handling image and audio files in iOS

Tags: ios, efficiency, file-handling

Currently I have an iOS app that downloads image and audio files from a server, but each view controller downloads its own set of image and audio files (This is because each view controller needs a different set of files). I want to know which if the following would be the most simple and efficient way of handling these files:

- Have each view controller store `UIImages` and `NSData` (audio) in an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`
- Have one singleton class to store all of these files (in memory)
- Store these files on disk and lazy loading them when necessary

BTW, the files are small in size (aprox. 15 - 20 KB) but potentially one user could have access to a lot of these files (aprox. 200). I have tried the first case, but the memory utilization rises significantly with a few minutes of use.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I have tried the first case, but the memory utilization rises significantly with a few minutes of use.

Comment: @gnat: questions of this nature tend to be asked on StackOverflow and might receive an answer quicker.

Comment: I think you can use singleton class to store these data and lazy loading them when necessary. I recommend you use a count-limited array to store them, when you add a new one and the array count reach the max, remove the data which is least used recently. To achieve that, you may need a timer to keep the access time of each data.